# Timber - don't display shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm using Timber on a WordPress site but am having an issue with shortcode content appearing on the homepage as html/text. I'm using `{{ post_content|exceprt(30) }}` to display the post content but this causes shortcodes to be displayed.

I'd prefer not to display any shortcode content at all on this page (either rendered or as html/text), if possible.

Is there any way to filter out shortcodes using Timber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the pipe stripshortcodes
`{{ post_content|exceprt(30)|stripshortcodes }}`

Comment: thanks @McKean, that worked great. Thought I had searched everywhere in the docs - obviously not.